# RegEx to extract file paths from a logfile

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, regular-expression

I need to get the file paths from a log file. I thought I will try this with regex.

A file path would look like this:

```
75/751234/751234V0001_test-tag1-tag02-75x75_01.jpg
```

I'm not a pro in Regex, so I only could get to the second slash with the following expression. I also get the beginning of the filenames via regex, but I can't get the several keywords that can follow.

```
([0-9]{2})[\/]([0-9]{2,10})[\/]
```

Now I'm still missing the regex for the actual filename. The filename always has a number at the beginning. After that, theoretically infinite keywords can follow.

The file extension can be .jpg, .tif, .zip, etc.

So the output should be the filepath

```
75/751234/751234V0001_test-tag1-tag02-75x75_01.jpg
```

Maybe someone has a solution, and or even an improvement to the regex I have so far.

Comment: It would benefit your question to include some actual lines from the log file.  I doubt that you will have to match the actual pathname, but that you instead could extract the pathnames based on other information in the log file.

Comment: `grep -Po '\d+/\d+/[\w-]+\.\w+'` with GNU `grep` may or may not be enough, hard to tell with the very few requirements you give about what should and shouldn't be matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your file paths are organized as follows:

- The filename starts with a multi-digit number.
- The path starts with a directory consisting of the first two digits of that number.
- It continues with a sub-directory consisting of the entire number.
- The file in question is directly in that sub-directory and, apart from starting with the above mentioned number, has an extension from a limited set of possibilities.

If you have different means of identifying lines that contain a filename, this might be preferable. If there are filenames of different patterns, and you want to focus on the pattern shown, then the following RegEx should work (example uses GNU `grep` in ERE mode):

```
grep -E -w -o '([[:digit:]]{2})/(\1[[:digit:]]+)/\2[^[:digit:]][^/]*\.(jpg|tif|zip)' logfile.txt
```

This uses backreferences (`\1` and `\2`) to ensure that "the same text" is matched at different places in the string.

- The string is required to start with two digits and a slash.
- It then needs to continue with the same two digits as the start, followed by an unspecified number (you can substitute the `+`  with `{2,10}` if the number has a fixed range) of further digits, and a slash
- Then, it starts with the same number as  the second path element, followed by a *non-digit character* (to ensure the number really is the same as the second path element) and any number of further characters except the `/` (to exclude files in sub-directories or guard agains multiple file paths being present on the same line) up to a final alternative of filename extensions (the amount of which you can adapt to your needs).
- The `-o` option ensures that only the matched part of the line (i.e. the file path) is returned. The `-w` option ensures that the result only matches full strings, i.e. not the sub-string of a possible longer filepath. This requires that filenames not contain spaces (which is a valid character for filenames!).

Note that strictly speaking, back-references are a feature guaranteed to work only in basic regular expressions, while alternatives are only guaranteed to work in extended regular expressions. GNU `grep` extended regular expressions do allow for the backreferences, so it works in this case (which maybe is not too much of a limitation).